# Magereport test unknown after adding RewriteRule

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

My store was showing all the installed patches on Magereport until I added `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xxx.xx.xxx
RewriteRule ^(index.php/)?admin/ - [L,R=403]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xxx.xx.xxx
RewriteRule ^(index.php/)?rss/ - [L,R=403]` to the .htaccess. I scan the store and everything is in grey(unknown)
I have reverted the changes in the .htaccess file (Deleted the rewrite command) but its still the same. 
Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"unknown" is explained as:

> We were unable to conclusively check your shop. The check might have
>   been blocked by other emergency measures you, or your provider, have
>   taken.

And this is what happened. You added **another emergency measure**, i.e. blocked access to /admin and ?rss completely, rendering all attempts to attack these URLs moot.

This not only prevents the check but also the exploits that are checked and probably currently unknown exploits as well. So it is good and you should keep your changes in the `.htaccess`.